# Scikit-learn GridSearch giving "ValueError: multiclass format is not supported" error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use GridSearch for parameter estimation of LinearSVC() as follows -

```
clf_SVM = LinearSVC()
params = {
          'C': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5],
          'tol': [1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5],
          'multi_class': ['ovr', 'crammer_singer'],
          }
gs = GridSearchCV(clf_SVM, params, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')
gs.fit(corpus1, y)
```

corpus1 has shape (1726, 7001) and y has shape (1726,)

This is a multiclass classification, and y has values from 0 to 3, both inclusive, i.e. there are four classes.

But this is giving me the following error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-220-0c627bda0543> in <module>()
      5           }
      6 gs = GridSearchCV(clf_SVM, params, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')
----> 7 gs.fit(corpus1, y)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    594 
    595         """
--> 596         return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
    597 
    598 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/grid_search.pyc in _fit(self, X, y, parameter_iterable)
    376                                     train, test, self.verbose, parameters,
    377                                     self.fit_params, return_parameters=True)
--> 378             for parameters in parameter_iterable
    379             for train, test in cv)
    380 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __call__(self, iterable)
    651             self._iterating = True
    652             for function, args, kwargs in iterable:
--> 653                 self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
    654 
    655             if pre_dispatch == "all" or n_jobs == 1:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in dispatch(self, func, args, kwargs)
    398         """
    399         if self._pool is None:
--> 400             job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
    401             index = len(self._jobs)
    402             if not _verbosity_filter(index, self.verbose):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.pyc in __init__(self, func, args, kwargs)
    136         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    137         # arguments in memory
--> 138         self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
    139 
    140     def get(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.pyc in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters)
   1238     else:
   1239         estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
-> 1240     test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
   1241     if return_train_score:
   1242         train_score = _score(estimator, X_train, y_train, scorer)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.pyc in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
   1294         score = scorer(estimator, X_test)
   1295     else:
-> 1296         score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
   1297     if not isinstance(score, numbers.Number):
   1298         raise ValueError("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s) instead."

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.pyc in __call__(self, clf, X, y)
    136         y_type = type_of_target(y)
    137         if y_type not in ("binary", "multilabel-indicator"):
--> 138             raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
    139 
    140         try:

ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

Comment: can you print the shapes of your variables used in .fit

Comment: corpus1 has shape (1726, 7001) and y has shape (1726,)

Comment: I also had the same issue, intsead of using 'roc_auc' scoring mechanism i have used 'accuracy' and it worked.

Answer (score 18):

Remove `scoring='roc_auc'` and it will work as `roc_auc` curve does not support categorical data.

Comment: `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` actually can, but I think it needs to be wrapped `https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html?highlight=roc_auc_score#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score`

Answer (score 13):

from:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score

"Note: this implementation is restricted to the binary classification task or multilabel classification task in label indicator format."

try:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
y = preprocessing.label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

before you train. this will perform a "one-hot" encoding of your y.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fd27da8cb43945de5e45
I've checked the shapes of y and corpus1, they are (1726, 4) and (1726, 7001)

Comment: your shape is now (1380,4)?  the transformed y should be (1726,4)

Comment: do all 4 classes exist in your y variable?

Comment: yes, see the first 30 lines here - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1f4104459f8d11b476f6

Comment: @user1269942 I am not seeing this "Note: this implementation is restricted to the binary classification task or multilabel classification task in label indicator format." on this [doc page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score) anymore. Could you please explain where I should be looking?

Comment: @Hawklaz  note that this was from 2014 and there are newer versions since. it appears that the function roc_auc_score has been updated a bit.  just look at the old docs versus the new docs.  other than that, I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

As it has been pointed out, you must first binarize `y`

```
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

and then use a multiclass learning algorithm like `OneVsRestClassifier` or `OneVsOneClassifier`. For example:

```
clf_SVM = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())
params = {
      'estimator__C': [0.5, 1.0, 1.5],
      'estimator__tol': [1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5],
      }
gs = GridSearchCV(clf_SVM, params, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc')
gs.fit(corpus1, y)
```

Comment: No longer true?

Comment: No longer true?

Answer (score 2):

For multiclass classification you have to specify some params in `roc_auc_score` function: `multi_class` and `average` (optionally). See [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html).

But how one could place these params in `GridSearchCV`? For these purposes, `make_scorer` function should be used.

```
multi_roc = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, average='weighted', multi_class='ovr', needs_proba=True)
searcher = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1), params, scoring=multi_roc, cv=skf, verbose=3, n_jobs=16)
```

See [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) and other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401493/how-to-create-customize-your-own-scorer-function-in-scikit-learn).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `to_categorical` rather than  `preprocessing.label_binarize()` depending on your problem. The problem is actually from using scoring=`roc_auc`. Note that `roc_auc` does not support categorical data.