# How to create/customize your own scorer function in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using [Support Vector Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) as an estimator in [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html). But I want to change the error function: instead of using the default (R-squared: coefficient of determination), I would like to define my own custom error function.

I tried to make one with `make_scorer`, but it didn't work.

I read the documentation and found that it's possible to create [custom estimators](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/contributing.html#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects), but I don't need to remake the entire estimator - only the error/scoring function.

I think I can do it by defining a callable as a scorer, like it says in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object).

But I don't know how to use an estimator: in my case SVR. Would I have to switch to a classifier (such as SVC)? And how would I use it?

My custom error function is as follows:

```
def my_custom_loss_func(X_train_scaled, Y_train_scaled):
    error, M = 0, 0
    for i in range(0, len(Y_train_scaled)):
        z = (Y_train_scaled[i] - M)
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] > M and (X_train_scaled[i] - Y_train_scaled[i]) > 0:
            error_i = (abs(Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(z))
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] > M and (X_train_scaled[i] - Y_train_scaled[i]) < 0:
            error_i = -(abs((Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(z)))
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] < M:
            error_i = -(abs(Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(-z))
    error += error_i
    return error
```

The variable `M` isn't null/zero. I've just set it to zero for simplicity.

Would anyone be able to show an example application of this custom scoring function? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Example of this:  (estimator, X, y)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As you saw, this is done by using `make_scorer` ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer)).

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.svm import SVR

import numpy as np

rng = np.random.RandomState(1)

def my_custom_loss_func(X_train_scaled, Y_train_scaled):
    error, M = 0, 0
    for i in range(0, len(Y_train_scaled)):
        z = (Y_train_scaled[i] - M)
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] > M and (X_train_scaled[i] - Y_train_scaled[i]) > 0:
            error_i = (abs(Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(z))
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] > M and (X_train_scaled[i] - Y_train_scaled[i]) < 0:
            error_i = -(abs((Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(z)))
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] < M:
            error_i = -(abs(Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(-z))
    error += error_i
    return error

# Generate sample data
X = 5 * rng.rand(10000, 1)
y = np.sin(X).ravel()

# Add noise to targets
y[::5] += 3 * (0.5 - rng.rand(X.shape[0]/5))

train_size = 100

my_scorer = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=True)

svr = GridSearchCV(SVR(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1),
                   scoring=my_scorer,
                   cv=5,
                   param_grid={"C": [1e0, 1e1, 1e2, 1e3],
                               "gamma": np.logspace(-2, 2, 5)})

svr.fit(X[:train_size], y[:train_size])

print svr.best_params_
print svr.score(X[train_size:], y[train_size:])
```

Comment: Hi. I know make_scorer but I want to define a new function which include a conditionals (If's up there). So How can I use "if" and "for" inside a function error? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem then. It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: I speak English very poorly, sorry. I'm trying to use "if conditional" and "for" inside "my_custom_loss_function". Like <br/> def my_custom_loss_func(X_train_scaled, Y_train_scaled):
    error, M = 0, 0
    for i in range(0, len(Y_train_scaled)):
        z = (Y_train_scaled[i] - M)
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] > M and (X_train_scaled[i] - Y_train_scaled[i]) > 0:...      <br/>   Can I do that? My laptop seems blocked. And I want to watch one by one all my datas in "X_train_scaled" and then operate on it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, your English is very good. Does this example work for you? If not, can you tell me where the problems are?

Comment: I tried the example. I don't know but... no It works! I think I had an error in dtype (between array and python; maybe I had "n_job=-1"). I really don't know but Im happy because it works now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 67):

Jamie has a fleshed out example, but here's an example using make_scorer straight from scikit-learn [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions):

```
import numpy as np
def my_custom_loss_func(ground_truth, predictions):
    diff = np.abs(ground_truth - predictions).max()
    return np.log(1 + diff)

# loss_func will negate the return value of my_custom_loss_func,
#  which will be np.log(2), 0.693, given the values for ground_truth
#  and predictions defined below.
loss  = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=False)
score = make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=True)
ground_truth = [[1, 1]]
predictions  = [0, 1]
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier
clf = DummyClassifier(strategy='most_frequent', random_state=0)
clf = clf.fit(ground_truth, predictions)
loss(clf,ground_truth, predictions) 

score(clf,ground_truth, predictions)
```

When defining a custom scorer via [`sklearn.metrics.make_scorer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html), the convention is that custom functions ending in `_score` return a value to maximize. And for scorers ending in `_loss` or `_error`, a value is returned to be minimized. You can use this functionality by setting the `greater_is_better` parameter inside [`make_scorer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html). That is, this parameter would be `True` for scorers where higher values are better, and `False` for scorers where lower values are better. [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) can then optimize in the appropriate direction.

You can then convert your function as a scorer as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import make_scorer

def custom_loss_func(X_train_scaled, Y_train_scaled):
    error, M = 0, 0
    for i in range(0, len(Y_train_scaled)):
        z = (Y_train_scaled[i] - M)
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] > M and (X_train_scaled[i] - Y_train_scaled[i]) > 0:
            error_i = (abs(Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(z))
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] > M and (X_train_scaled[i] - Y_train_scaled[i]) < 0:
            error_i = -(abs((Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(z)))
        if X_train_scaled[i] > M and Y_train_scaled[i] < M:
            error_i = -(abs(Y_train_scaled[i] - X_train_scaled[i]))**(2*np.exp(-z))
    error += error_i
    return error


custom_scorer = make_scorer(custom_loss_func, greater_is_better=True)
```

And then pass `custom_scorer` into [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) as you would any other scoring function: `clf = GridSearchCV(scoring=custom_scorer)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read this documentation in Scikit and I read about custom function too, but I didn't get it worked. Afterwards Jamie Bull wrote his "make_scorer" and I tried again... It works! I don't know how or why. I was chanching to Windows 10 and re-installing all my programs... May be it was: Windows 10 plus new version Anaconda (I run python under Anaconda). Anyway, thanks a lot! (I'm not programmer or computer scientist... so its hard to me).