# post-process cross-validated prediction before scoring

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a regression problem, where I am cross-validating the results and evaluating the performance. I know beforehand that the ground truth cannot be smaller than zero. Therefore, I would like to intercept the predictions, before they are fed to the score metric, to clip the predictions to zero. I thought that using the make_scorer function would be useful to do this. Is it possible to somehow post-process the predictions after cross-validation, but before applying an evaluation metric to it?

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

# X = Stacked feature vectors
# y = ground truth vector
# regr = some regression estimator

#### How to indicate that the predictions need post-processing 
#### before applying the score function???
scoring = {'r2': make_scorer(r2_score),
           'neg_mse': make_scorer(mean_squared_error)}

scores = cross_validate(regr, X, y, scoring=scoring, cv=10)
```

PS: I know there are constrained estimators, but I wanted to see how a heuristic approach like this would perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is wrap those scorers you're looking to use (`r2_score`, `mean_squared_error`) in a custom scorer function using `make_scorer()` as you suggested.

Take a look at [this part of the sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions) and [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401493/how-to-create-customize-your-own-scorer-function-in-scikit-learn) for some examples. In particular, your function can do something like this:

```
def clipped_r2(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_clipped = np.clip(y_pred, 0, None)
    return r2_score(y_true, y_pred_clipped)

def clipped_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_clipped = (y_pred, 0, None)
    return mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred_clipped)
```

This allows you to do the post-processing right within the scorer before calling the scoring function (in this case `r2_score` or `mean_squared_error`). Then to use it just use make_scorer like you were doing above, setting `greater_is_better` according to whether the scorer is a scoring function (like r2, greater is better), or loss function (mean_squared_error is better when it's 0, i.e. less):

```
scoring = {'r2': make_scorer(clipped_r2, greater_is_better=True),
           'neg_mse': make_scorer(clipped_mse, greater_is_better=False)}
scores = cross_validate(regr, X, y, scoring=scoring, cv=10)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had indeed looked at those resources. I was only confused about how those (clipping) evaluation metrics would know what y_pred is? This should be passed on internally from the regressor for every fold. Is y_pred defined from within cross_validate somewhere? I'll try nonetheless.

Comment: That happens internally in the `cross_validate` function. You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L554) if you're interested, but it's a bit hard to read because you have to bounce around between a bunch of functions to keep track of where the data is actually used to fit and score the model. But yes, the point is that the y_pred and y_test there are for each cross_validation fold.