# How to input custom metric in RandomizedSearchCV?

Tags: python, pandas, decision-tree, sklearn-pandas

I need to choose best model by the metice smape_final. For this, I wrote a function:

```
def smape(A, F):
    return 100/len(A) * np.sum(2 * np.abs(F - A) / (np.abs(A) + np.abs(F)))
```

which I  use later:

```
parameters = {'max_depth':range(1,30,1), 'n_estimators':range(10,51,10)}
rgr_rand_frst = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 12345), parameters, cv=5, random_state=12345)
rgr_rand_frst.fit(features_train, target_train)
predicted_valid = rgr_rand_frst.predict(features_valid)
smape_final=round(smape(predicted_valid,target_valid)[0]*0.25+smape(predicted_valid,target_valid)[1]*0.75,4)

print('Final-smape: ',smape_final)
print('Best params: ',rgr_rand_frst.best_params_)
```

But RandomizedSearchCV uses some preinstalled metric to choose best parmetrs. I know I can use some from preinstalled in sklear (r2, auc_score, etc) but the goal is to use custom metric smape_final. How it can be done?

Note: target_train consists of 2 columns

Comment: your `smape` definition needs `axis=0` in `np.sum` to return as many scores as your target variable's columns (i.e., 2 here). Then make your `smape_final` a function with two arguments. Rest is duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401493/how-to-create-customize-your-own-scorer-function-in-scikit-learn).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [make_scorer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) to wrap a custom loss function

Comment: Thank you, but can you give some particular example how it can be done, approximately?