# GridSearchCV for the multi-class SVM in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, grid-search

I am trying to learn how to find the best parameters for a classifier. So, I am using **GridSearchCV** for a multi-class classification problem. A dummy code was generated on [Does not GridSearchCV support multi-class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265110/does-not-gridsearchcv-support-multi-class) I am just using that code with n_classes=3.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,label_binarize
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score, make_scorer

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=3000, n_features=10, weights=[0.1, 0.9, 0.3],n_classes=3, n_clusters_per_class=1,n_informative=2)

pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVC(kernel='rbf', class_weight='auto'))

param_space = dict(svc__C=np.logspace(-5,0,5), svc__gamma=np.logspace(-2, 2, 10))

f1_score
my_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, greater_is_better=True)

gscv = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_space, scoring=my_scorer)
```

I am trying to do **One-hot encoding** as advised here [Scikit-learn GridSearch giving "ValueError: multiclass format is not supported" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210471/scikit-learn-gridsearch-giving-valueerror-multiclass-format-is-not-supported). Also, sometimes there will be dataset like `Toxic Comment Classification dataset on Kaggle` which will give you binarized labels.

```
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
for i in classes:    
gscv.fit(X, y[i])

print gscv.best_params_
```

I am getting:

```
ValueError: bad input shape (2000L, 3L)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. My objective is to find the best parameters for a multi-class classification problem.

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems in the two parts of your code.

1) Let's start with first part when you have not one-hot encoded the labels. You see, `SVC` supports the multi-class cases just fine. But the `f1_score` when combined with (inside) `GridSearchCV` does not.

`f1_score` by default returns the scores of positive label in case of binary classification so will throw error in your case.

**OR** It also can return an array of scores (one for each class), but GridSearchCV only accepts a single value as score because it needs that for finding the best score and best combination of hyper-parameters. So you need to pass the averaging method in `f1_score` to get a single value from the array.

According to the [`f1_score` documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score), following averaging methods are allowed:

> average : string, [None, ‘binary’ (default), ‘micro’, ‘macro’,
>   ‘samples’, ‘weighted’]

So change your make_scorer like this:

```
my_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score, greater_is_better=True, average='micro')
```

Change the `'average'` param above as it suits you.

2) Now coming to the second part: When you one-hot encode the labels, the shape of `y` becomes 2-d, but [`SVC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) only supports a 1-d array as `y` as specified in the documentation:

> ```
> fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)[source]
>
>     X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_samples, n_features)
>     y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
> ```

But even if you encode the labels and use a classifier which supports the 2-d labels, then the first error will have to be solved. So I would advice you not to one-hot encode the labels and just change the `f1_score`.

Comment: Thanks, @Vivek Kumar I can manually select the y(target) to solve Problem #2. However, then I think I need to fit(X,y) and GridSearch inside the loop which I am not sure if I can do that. This is the main question.

Comment: `for i in classes:    
gscv.fit(X, y[i])`
 Like this. In this way I will only have 1-D for labels.